# Wann sagt man "funktional" und wann "funktionell"?

Tags: meaning

Mir ist der Unterschied nicht klar und auch aus der Beschreibung des Duden werde ich nicht schlau. Welche der folgenden Sätze ist richtig?

> Die ursprüngliche erste Ausführung muss danach fortgeführt werden können, ohne dass es zu einer **funktionellen** Beeinträchtigung kommt.
>
> Die ursprüngliche erste Ausführung muss danach fortgeführt werden können, ohne dass es zu einer **funktionalen** Beeinträchtigung kommt.

Der inhaltliche Gehalt der Aussage sollte sein: Die Funktion muss ihre Spezifikation weiterhin erfüllen.

Mir gefällt der zweite Satz besser, weil der erste Satz eher nach einer plastischen/greifbaren Funktion (z.b. dass das Gehen weiterhin funktionieren muss), als nach einem abstrakt definierten Verhalten, klingt. Aber ich sehe keinen wirklichen begrifflichen Unterschied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*funktionell* heißt: Etwas tut, was es soll, es erfüllt seine Funktion, es funktioniert.

> Der Mixer ist sehr funktionell, mit 16 Geschwindigkeitsstufen, 1000 Watt Leistung und einem ergonomischen Handgriff.

*funktional* heißt: Die Funktion betreffend - Ein Substantiv *bezieht sich* auf die Funktion.

> Die funktionalen Eigenschaften des Mixers sind perfekt - Er liegt gut in der Hand und macht, was er soll.

Eine *funktionelle Beeinträchtigung* wäre nach dieser Erklärung eine "Beeinträchtigung, die funktioniert", was natürlich Unsinn ist.

Vergleiche ein ähnliches Wortpaar: *originell* und *original* - *Originell* heißt hier ebenfalls "ursprünglich", während *original* "den Ursprung betreffend" bedeutet.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung. Beim Beispiel des Mixers, dessen *funktionale* Eigenschaften perfekt sind, ließe sich kontrastiv ergänzen: "seine *ästhetischen* Eigenschaften sind aber eine Zumutung".

Comment: Wieso Unsinn, ich suche ständig nach funktionellen Beeinträchtigungen, wenn meine Frau neue Schuhe kaufen will !! ;) SCNR